# Why is IntelliJ marking my file red despite no errors?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I'm integrated with VCS Perforce, and I confirmed that this is a file in my active changelist.
I'm on IJ 12.1.4

Comment: There are errors. Check the logs.

Comment: No errors. I compiled the module and even my whole project. The server is running fine as well. It's something else..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it! It's marked like that because I had done a p4 sync and the file had been changed since I had in my changelist, and so it needed a resolve..

IntelliJ should say what the problem is when hovering upon the file name.

Comment: Saw the same thing when fixing conflicts with git and initially assumed it was a compilation problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Version Control issue. 
For me, I had to right click on the file, then choose "Git" -> "Use my commits"
[image]